# Example of Helly's selection lemma where the convergence is not an actual distribution function?

Tags: probability-theory

Helly's selection lemma states: each given sequence $F_{n}$ of cumulative distribution functions on $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ possesses a subsequence $F_{n_{j}}$ with the property that $F_{n_{j}}(x) \rightarrow F(x)$ at each continuity point $x$ of a possibly defective distribution function $F$.

My question is that can we construct one example where the limiting $F$ is indeed defective? Each $F_n$ is an actual distribution function, so why the limiting function not a distribution function?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $X_n \sim N(0,n^2)$

$$
F_n(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}e^{\frac{t^2}{2n^2}}dt
$$
By change of variables $y = t/n$ we have
$$
F_n(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\frac xn} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy
$$
as $n \to \infty$ note that $x/n \to 0$ and the integral is the distribution of a standard normal distribution. This implies $F_n(x) \to \frac 12, \forall x$ which is not a distribution function.